# What is the mechanism/algorithm involved in functions that perform a fade of some sort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, fade, slide

What is the mechanism/algorithm involved in functions that perform a fade of some sort?  What are some links or resources i can check out when it comes to this matter.

Comment: @Chaos - You sure? I thought it was Voodoo.

Comment: @patrick - I sure hope so, it is not exactly rocket science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very very simply put, it's usually a function setting the `opacity` CSS property gradually (`i = i+1`) from one value (0...100) to another.

A [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) makes sure the function that controls the gradual fading is called every x milliseconds. That way, the fade effect can take place while the page remains functional.

As for resources, you can take a look into how the frameworks do it; however, being highly optimized, their code is probably not good stuff for learning. There were framework-independent fading scripts on sites like [DynamicDrive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/), they should provide a good insight in how this stuff basically works (IIRC, the scripts there were often awful code but still half-way understandable.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you entered a jQuery tag:

- [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)
- [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Ah, the old fadeIn/fadeOut algorithm.